# How to fix a php code which does not insert into the db?

Tags: php, mysql

My php does not insert into the db : I really do not know why : please I need help I cant figure out the problem :

```
<form action="insertfixture.php" method="post">

<tr><td>Date</td><td><input type = "text" name = "match_date" ></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value="update"></td></tr>
</form>
<?php 
include_once("connect.php");?>
$match_date=(isset($_POST['match_date']))? trim($_POST['match_date']): '';

$sql="INSERT INTO fixture(match_date)
VALUES ('$match_date')";
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
#if something goes wrong then tell the user 
if($result){
echo "New fixture Successfully added</br>";

}
else {
echo "We are sorry no Fixture inserted ";
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Well, what errors are you getting?

Comment: @j0869 echo "We are sorry no Fixture inserted ";

Comment: no space between fixture and ( but apart from that what other errors you getting? are you remembering case sensitivity on unix systems ?

Comment: You need to debug your code. Read [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1409082)

Comment: change it to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()."<br />$sql");`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: @Dave die is not by any means a good error handling method. He should use PDO in exception mode.

Comment: First you fix your glaring [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) hole.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan I'm not getting into the PDO arguement as he's not using PDO regardless of what is better or not we're not teaching him to code we're helping fix a specific problem.

Comment: @Dave I think the ongoing intent of the PDO force-feeding is to curb the subsequent questions OP will inevitably have by instilling him with "best practices" now, regardless of any specific problems.

Comment: The problem is PDO is complex and tbh quite crap its alot harder to pick up than learning the basics.

Comment: @Dave Say what? PDO complex? It has exec and query member functions. What's so complex about that?

Answer (score 3):

You have closed your php close tag after include_once function. This should be problem.

```
<form action="insertfixture.php" method="post">

<tr><td>Date</td><td><input type = "text" name = "match_date" ></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value="update"></td></tr>
</form>
<?php 
include_once("connect.php");
$match_date=(isset($_POST['match_date']))? trim($_POST['match_date']): '';

$sql="INSERT INTO fixture(match_date) VALUES ('$match_date')";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("<br>Error:" .mysql_error()); 
#if something goes wrong then tell the user 
if($result){
echo "New fixture Successfully added</br>";

}
else {
echo "We are sorry no Fixture inserted ";
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
include_once("connect.php");?>
```

There is an extra PHP closing tag that should not be there. Replace the line with:

```
include_once("connect.php");
```